# What is the low level magmatic frequency to be used to get signal out from a metal faraday cage?

Tags: electromagnetism

I need to track the inventory kept in a sealed metal container at the Gate level before delivery.

I am not sure if RFID tracking can help since the signal tends to bounce on and will not reach the antenna / reader kept at the gate.

My other option is to address this by tagging items with IOT based Wifi / GSM sensors and transmitting data to cloud or mobile phone from the closed container using low magnetic frequency.

Can anyone suggest if this could work and what levels of lower magnetic frequency should be used to achieve this solution and can it be workable.

TIA,

Best regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Is this just one piece per container? If so, isn't the easy solution to RFID (or even bar-code) the container run the inventory off that?